# Uploading multiple files to Firebase Storage Very Slow

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload two files to firebase storage at the same time. From what I understand this is not possible so what I did was try to upload one first and then the next file once the first is done. 
It is working now, however the upload speed is very slow. Is this because of an issue with my code or is it because Im waiting for two uploads as opposed to one.

```
var index = 0
var urls = [String]()
fileprivate func uploadToServer(data: Any) {

    if index == 0 {
        let filename = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("posts").child(filename)
        storageRef.putData(data as! Data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, err) in
            if let err = err {
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
                print("Failed to upload post image:", err)
                self.showHUDwithError(error: err)
                return
            }
            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (downloadURL, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to fetch downloadURL:", err)
                    self.showHUDwithError(error: err)
                    return
                }
                guard let thisUrl = downloadURL?.absoluteString else { return }
                self.urls.append(thisUrl)
                self.index = self.index + 1
                if self.type == "image" {
                    // we are done then so do the save to server call here
                    self.saveToDatabaseWithImageUrl()
                } else {
                    self.uploadToServer(data: self.videoUrl as Any)
                }
            })
        }
        return
    }

    if index == 1 {
        let filename = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("posts").child(filename)
        storageRef.putFile(from: data as! URL, metadata: nil) { (metadata, err) in
            if let err = err {
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
                print("Failed to upload post image:", err)
                self.showHUDwithError(error: err)
                return
            }
            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (downloadURL, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to fetch downloadURL:", err)
                    self.showHUDwithError(error: err)
                    return
                }
                guard let thisUrl = downloadURL?.absoluteString else { return }
                self.urls.append(thisUrl)
                self.saveToDatabaseWithImageUrl()
                self.index = 0
            })
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it is not possible to upload multiple files at the same time? While I never tried, I don't think the SDKs or server prevent it.

Comment: Not sure what the point of that code is. You should really have a function that is passed the file or url or whatever it is you're uploading and let it do the upload. They are all asynchronous so you could have 10 files uploading simultaneously. Not sure what is mean by 'waiting for two uploads' as they are done when they are done and the closure will complete when the files are uploaded. That upload speed is dependent on your internet connection. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I misunderstood what I read somewhere, I thought you could not upload two files at once because there is no way to batch them together. I believe the upload being slow is due to not having the right compression set up.